# Is it possible to integrate selenium with any AI tool that gives it capability to have better or AI (artificial intelligence) ways to locate elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, artificial-intelligence

We are working on selenium framwork which uses Java as framework language. There are more than 400 + test scripts written in our framework. This application is mostly stable but there are some design changes happening every now and then. Is there any way to integrate selenium with the ai tools to locate the elements ?
We cannot migrate 400+ test case to the new tool , so we are looking for the solution where we can integrate any ai tools to locate element diynamicaly and avoid failure because of change in design

Basically I am looking for replacement of below command from Appium in Selenium webdriver

```
driver.elementByCustom(‘ai:cart’);
```

Refrence Link : https://medium.com/testdotai/adding-ai-to-appium-f8db38ea4fac